# why javascript `var undefined` is OK but `var null` throw error

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

why does browser throw Error for `var null;` ?

I am reading [Javascript Garden-undefined](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/zh/#core.undefined) and I know `undefined` is a global variable different from `null`.

But I am just curious about that why it throws Error when do`var null;`
in contrast, when `var Number=123`,`var Boolean=123`,`var Object=123`,`var undefined=123`(although useless), etc.,it's ok.

As far as I know, `null` is not a reserved word and keyword in JavaScript. It should be a primitive type.

How does `var` work exactly in relation to `null`?

Comment: "Additionally, the literals null, true, and false cannot be used as identifiers in ECMAScript." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords

Comment: @mplungjan thank you and it's useful.I don't know NullLiteral, and BooleanLiterals before and it's really a puzzle for me.I want to know why you think it's a duplicate.should I delete this anwser if I got the down vote?

Comment: I tried but I cannot find an official document that says "null" is a _reserved word_ - we all just agree it is and I personally do not care. I never use variable names that MIGHT be reserved. Here is a cool tester: https://mothereff.in/js-variables

Comment: thx all,**I know the question is useless in effect**,but I am just curious about it, I am a curious boy~thank you for all of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is `null` is a [reserved identifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar) and `undefined` isn't.

From the documentation:

> The literals null, true, and false cannot be used as identifiers in ECMAScript.

This is part of the grammar definition, while global variables are just things you can (usually) override.

Comment: I don't totally agree with you.null is not a reserved keyword.It's just a   literal.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Literals

Comment: The comment from @mplungjan is also quite specific, and I'll repeat it here: "Additionally, the literals `null`, `true`, and `false` **cannot be used as identifiers** in ECMAScript." There's no such provision for `undefined`. I don't know what you want that's more official than that other than a letter from Eich with a wax seal on it, perhaps?